# Manipulating UVs does not show in viewport with texture applied

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm probably just missing something but I've been struggling with this for well over and hour now. Here's the deal:

I've created a basic material, imported and image, and applied it to my model. I've also gone and quickly unwrapped it. See here:
[image]

Now when I scale the UVs like below, there is no change in how the texture is applied to the object. I tried creating a texture coordinate node and plugging the UV into the vector of the image node but no luck. What am I missing?
[image]

Comment: Maybe you've created a second UV map and that's the one that is selected for rendering (in the Properties editor > Object Data > UV maps)?

Comment: Ah-ha! That was it. I feel like and idiot, but problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go in the *Properties* editor > *Object Data* > *UV maps*. You've created a second UV map and that's the one that is selected for rendering, so select the other one.